# Passing variables and data through a regular web page link?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm working with a page where I'm trying to submit data when a link is clicked. I already know how to do this with POST and GET using javascript buttons, but how do I get the same effect when I'm working with HTML links?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a plain link you can pass them as query parameters on the link (which is a GET operation)

```
<a href="/myapp/somecontroller.php?id=17&name=fred">Save</a>
```

If you have a plain HTML form with no javascript to handle the button press you can put things in hidden fields

```
<form name="theform" method="post" action="/myapp/somecontroller.php">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="17">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
 ...
</form>
```

This doesn't require any javascript.

Comment: You can also add GET variables to the form's action attribute, i.e. <form action="something.php?id=17&name=fred">

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your data to another page using **GET** or **POST**.

Please note that when passing the data you must consider its purpose. If passing the data does not cause any changes in your application you should use **GET**. Otherwise, you should use **POST**.

If you have a user management page for instance. When you are only displaying user details you should be using **GET** because it is not making any sort of changes: `http://www.mywebsite.com/user.php?user=10`.

However if users change their details, you should use **POST** because it is changing the user's data:

```
<form name="userDetails" method="post" action="saveChanges.php">
   <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" />
   <input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
```

Alternativelly, you can also use **Cookies**. You can save the data into a cookie that can be used throughout your web application.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a query string: Something like this:

```
<a href="page.php?id=1&display=asdf">text</a>
```

This way, you get this as query string variables.

Comment: No semicolon before =, and the ampersands need to be &amp;

Comment: I have yet to encounter a browser/server that gives a damn about & v &amp; in links

Comment: To make the page validate it's important to use the HTML entity instead of the literal character.

Comment: The colon was a typo - now fixed. The & was correct. Here, two variables were passed: id with value of 1 and display with value of asdf.

Comment: No, the & is not correct, it should be &amp;, as in any time you use a literal ampersand in HTML content. Browsers may let you get away with &display for now, but only by accident and only until someone adds a ‘&display;’ entity to a browser. Don't count on knowing every possible entity name.

Comment: Yep. You're right. Somehow had the browser address-bar in mind when writing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data values from one plain .html page to another, you can use these techniques:

storing the data value in a cookie

storing the value in the rewritable property window.name

appending the value to the destination page's URL as a query string

storing the value in a JavaScript variable of another frame (if you use frames)

A nice demo of the above techniques is in the JavaScript FAQ collection - see
[Passing parameters to a page](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/passingp.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on what you're asking, but this is what it sounds like:

You know how to use POST and GET, aka HTML forms, to pass data between pages. You're using Javascript buttons.

There are a couple of interpretations of "Javascript buttons":

Are you doing something like

```
(1) <input type="submit" onclick="doSomething();" value="Save my data" />
(2) <input type="button" onclick="doSomething();" value="Save my data"  />
(3) <button onclick="doSomething();">Save my data</button>
```

Or something like

```
(4) <input type="submit" value="Save my data" />
```

1, 2, and 3 are examples of using javascript to make the buttons do stuff. ("Javascript buttons"). 4 is a standard HTML FORM button -- Javascript is NOT being used; the standard HTML form behaviors will cause the button to submit the data to whatever page is specified in the FORM tag (something like `<form method="get" action="datacollection.php">` ).

Now, the thing to understand is that POST/GET are ways to send data around between webpages -- between the browser and the server. The process of sending the data around can be triggered by HTML (an `<a>` link), Javascript (a function that calls a URL or triggers that a FORM get submitted), or FORM elements like `<input type="submit" />`.

I'm not intending any offense, but the way you asked your question makes me think that you're not trying to figure out different formats to transfer the data to the receiving page (as other posters discuss), and figuring out how to parse cookie values or iterate through your form fields to create a query string would be really challenging.

So here are some options:

1. If your form was already using Javascript to submit the form (cases 1, 2, or 3 above), you just add the same onclick part to an HTML link:

   Save my data

The function submitMyForm might look something like this:

```
function submitMyForm() {
  // Get the form object -- you can also do this with the document.form array
  var myForm = document.getElementById( 'userdata' );
  // use the submit method of the form object
  myForm.submit();

}
```

So in summary, you'll add a javascript behavior ("event handler")  to a normal HTML anchor link. One note -- in general, users expect the rule "links go places, buttons do things". It's not a hard and fast rule, but people generally are happier when a button is used for things like submitting form data.