# How do I rewrite URLs to make them shorter and not show any GET variables in the address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a link structure on single index.php page such as index.php?lang=eng&theme=dark&page=shop for example. I do need to pick up GET variables from the link to give appropriate content and configuration to each visited page. However I just want to show name of the page such as default.php or I if possible I want to show something like shop.php if the page=shop and chat.php if the page=chat. Can anyone recommend me what technique I should use at all?

Comment: Instead of passing variables in GET method you can try passing them in POST method.

Comment: For example yeas or store these config values in the session.

Comment: This is for Navigation Links and language switches so I don't think that POST is going to work here. for example: default.php?lang=eng&theme=dark&page=shop&item=tv (this shouls be just rewritten as: default.php/shop/ or something similar and not show all the variables as long as they are still accessible from within the PHP code to make calculations

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that, you should use POST rather than GET because it won't show its variables in the URL bar.

In PHP, you can find the value of POST variables by using `$_POST['var']` rather than `$_GET['var']` but how will you use open them in the first place if they won't show in a URL?

The answer is to use a form which appears to be a normal link, with elements inside it as variables for the PHP POST stuff. Here's an example:

```
...
<form name="openPage2" method="post" action="path/to/page2.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en" />
   <input type="submit" value="Page 2"/>
</form>
...
```

Now, what this will do is quite simple really. Say the current page containing this form is `mywebsite.com/index.php`. There's a button labelled Page 2 and everything else in the form is hidden. When you click page 2, the browser will go to `mywebsite.com/path/to/page2.php` without any **visible** variables in the URL bar. But, we've put hidden inputs into the form which will be submitted as POST when you click Page 2. Meaning, on Page 2, you can do this to get the language:

```
...
<?php
    $lang = $_POST['lang'];
    setLang($lang);
?>
...
```

and $lang will now be `"en"` because that's the form value. You can put as many hidden inputs as you like and none of them will show up in the URL bar because they are POST, not GET.

Hope that helped!

Comment: I still want to stick with GET variables, I just dont want them to show up in the URL so just shortenning the URL like WordPress does is a better option I think.

Comment: You mean you want to compress and obfuscate the variables? In that case you can have site.com/?thing=<abc> where abc is your obfuscated text and then a function to decode it in your php script.

Comment: And I accidentally posted that too early but now it's complete

Comment: Thank you, that is probably even better than what I was trying to come up with but I am not that advanced. can you have a look at my comment at my own question it explains and thanks for good advice.

Comment: The only way I see is possible is with POST. Maybe you could try a hidden form with a visible submit button, with the method POST, which means it will act like a link with ?a=1&b=2 but won't show those variables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668920/passing-variables-and-data-through-a-regular-web-page-link (answer 1)

Comment: I will give it a try then no problems I am waiting. what is mod_rewrite for then in PHP?